# передать число в строку таблицы php yii2

Tags: php, yii2

как передать число 0 или 1 в строку таблицы ,

если условие будет примерно такая,

если time start(тут время начало) пройдет тогда передай в таблицу time 1
и соотвественно если не прошло время то 0

Comment: Зачем переводить true/false в 1/0? Сразу передавайте булевое значение, а вообще совет почитать что-то из книг, не любите читать, посмотрите уроки. Не нужно брать сразу фреймворк и потом на каждом шаге создавать вопросы, так вы ничему не выучитесь.

Comment: нет не true/false, а  1 => 'Активный',
                    2 => 'Неактивный',
                ],
                'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                    $active = $model->{$column->attribute}===1;
                    return \yii\helpers\Html::tag(
                        'span',
                        $active ? 'Активный' : 'Неактивный',
                        [
                            'class' => 'label label-' . ($active ? 'success' : 'danger'),
                        ]

Comment: и мне надо просто передать число в таблицу которая отвечает за этот код

Comment: я бы с радостью прочиталбы или еще лучше просмотрелбы но увы ничего не нашел про данную проблему

Comment: @nike проблема нызвается `PHP`, затем вторая проблема `MySql` затем третья проблема `PHP и MySQL`, затем уже проблема `yii2` и `yii2 ActiveRecord`, гугл оплатите, там море инфы по каждой из проблема